# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf') with Firebase v9 Modular React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I got this simple form that registers users and send the uid and email data to a collection on firestore, im using latest version of Firebase 9 w/ modular.
The authentication works great, but the firestore part doesnt. It throws me an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')
at Function.fromString (path.ts:229)
at Ac2 (reference.ts:374)
at Login.jsx:29
```

I dont know what does that mean, I am trying to upload the email and uid information of the registered user to firestore with the order of 'users / (and here the useruid)/ all the user data' but throws me that error.

I leave my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react'
import { auth, db } from "../firebase"
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { collection, doc, addDoc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 



function Login() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [pass, setPass] = useState('')
    const [error, setError] = useState('')
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState('')

    const ProcessData = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        registro()
    }

    const registro = useCallback(async() => {

        try {
            await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, pass)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                const user = userCredential.user;
                setUserData(user)
            })
            
            
            await addDoc(collection(db, 'users', userData.uid), {
                email: userData.email,
                uid: userData.uid
              })
                
            
            
            setEmail('')
            setPass('')
            setError('')

        } catch (error) {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;

            setError(errorMessage)
            console.log(error)
        }
            
    }, [email, pass, error, userData])

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Registro</h3>
            <form onSubmit={ProcessData}>
                <label>Email Adress</label>
                <input
                type="email"
                placeholder="Email Address"
                onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                value={email}
                />
                <label>Password</label>
                <input
                type="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                onChange={e => setPass(e.target.value)}
                value={pass}
                />
                <button type="submit">Registrarse</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Comment: The code snippet you've provided has no code calling `.indexOf`. Surely there is a stacktrace accompanying the error that tells you where the error originates from. Can you update your question to include the full error message and stacktrace?

Comment: @DrewReese i update the whole error message that throws me, check it out c:

Comment: add the part of your code where you call `.indexOf`

Comment: What is line 29 of `Login` component?

Comment: Hi @PeterO. Is that nowhere in my code do I use indexOf, I can't find a line of code where it makes references to "indexOf"

Comment: @DrewReese Line 29 of Login: await addDoc(collection(db, 'users', userData.uid), {

Comment: Ah, I think I see now.... `userData.uid` is likely the culprit since `userData` is still the initial empty string (`''`) state value. Remember, React state updates are asynchronously processed, so the `setUserData(user)` won't have updated the `userData` state yet when it's referenced a few lines below in `collection(db, 'users', userData.uid)`. Why is the initial `userData` state a string type, but later updated to be an object type? You should strive to maintain consistent variable typing.

Comment: Just make sure the values you pass to `doc` reference, not `undefined`, so `collection(db, 'users', userData.uid)` the `userData` & `uid` of it are both defined or temporarily pass empty string `collection(db, 'users', userData.uid || '')`, or better to avoid it to fire the request when it's initialized

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to read data from `userData` state while adding a document. Try passing the params directly from `user` object returned so any path segment in `doc()` won't be undefined:

```js
try {
  const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, pass)
  setUserData(user)
  
  // db must not be undefined
  // try console.log(db) to ensure it's a Firestore instance
  await setDoc(doc(db, 'users', user.uid), {
  //    ^^^    ^^^<-- DocumentReference and not CollectionReference
    email: user.email,
    uid: user.uid
  })
                
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

Also you were passing 2 path segments in `collection()` which might return an error since a CollectionReference path takes odd number of path segments. If you want user's UID as document ID then use `setDoc` since `addDoc` will generate a random ID.

Comment: Ah, much simpler than my solution. I feel almost silly to *not* have seen that. Kudos.

Answer (score 3):

## Issue

> Line 29 of Login: await addDoc(collection(db, 'users', userData.uid),
> {

`userData.uid` is likely the culprit since `userData` is still the initial empty string (`''`) state value. Remember, React state updates are asynchronously processed, so the `setUserData(user)` won't have updated the `userData` state yet when it's referenced a few lines below in `collection(db, 'users', userData.uid)`.

## Solution

I suggest splitting out the second half of the `registro` function into an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `userData` state to issue the side-effect of adding the document.

```
function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [pass, setPass] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userData) {
      const { email, uid } = userData;
      try {
        addDoc(collection(db, 'users', uid), { email, uid });
      } catch (error) {
        const { code, message } = error;

        setError(message);
        console.log(error);
      }
    }

  }, [userData]);

  const ProcessData = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    registro();
  }

  const registro = useCallback(async() => {
    try {
      await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, pass)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          const { user } = userCredential;
          setUserData(user);
        });
            
      setEmail('');
      setPass('');
      setError('');

    } catch (error) {
      const { code, message } = error;

      setError(message);
      console.log(error);
    }
            
  }, [email, pass, error, userData])

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```